# Reading a .txt into a definition

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to read from a simple text file that looks like this:

```
11
eggs
1.17
milk
3.54
bread
1.50
coffee
3.57
sugar
1.07
flour
1.37
apple
.33
cheese
4.43
orange
.37
bananas
.53
potato
.19
```

What I'm trying to do is ask an input for a file name such as "milk" than to print the price of that. I am trying to use dictionaries.

Here is my code:

```
def main():
    key = ''
    infile = open('shoppinglist.txt', 'r')

    count = infile.readline()
    groceries = {}

    print('This program keeps a running total of your shopping list.')
    print('Use \'EXIT\' to exit.')

    grocery = input('Enter an item: ')

    for line in infile:
        line = line.strip()
        if key == '':
            key = line
        else:
            groceries[key] = line #maybe use here float(line) instead
            key = ''

    print ('Your current total is $'+ groceries[grocery])

main()
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

This program keeps a running total of your shopping list.
Use 'EXIT' to exit.
Enter an item: eggs
Your current total is $1.17

Enter an item: bread
Your current total is $3.00

Enter an item: sugar
Your current total is $4.07

Enter an item: EXIT
Your final total is $4.07

Comment: Is this homework? If it is, labeling homework questions as such allows us to better help you. Also, you're more likely to get a helpful response if you indicate what's wrong with your code (perhaps an error, or a comparison of output vs expected output), rather than just pasting it and asking us to have a look.

Comment: added the python tag, which I think is the correct language... if it isn't you should retag it to include the language you are using.

Comment: Yes jared it is for a homework assignment. and it is also for python. I will edit the code with the expected output.

Comment: I am stuck trying to figure out how to add the values and keeping it in a running total

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have. You already had a pretty ready code.
Look at the diferences:

-You were overwritting `groceries`
-you were not reading the value from the dictionary
-In python < 3x you shoud use raw_input instead of input. If you are in py3k input is OK
-Also you do not need parenthesis for print in py2.x. You do in py3k
-Maybe the only bizarre thing for a homework here is the use of % in print. It means that %s will be substituted by the string after the last % sign
-Be careful because cost of groceries are actually strings so you can not make mathematical operations with them. First you should convert them to floats.

```
def main():
    key = ''
    infile = open('shoppinglist.txt', 'r')

    count = infile.readline()
    groceries = {}

    print('This program keeps a running total of your shopping list.')
    print('Use \'EXIT\' to exit.')

    grocery = raw_input('Enter an item: ')

    for line in infile:
        line = line.strip()     #take out newlines codes.
        if key == '':
            key = line
        else:
            groceries[key] = line     #maybe use here float(line) instead
            key = ''

    print 'Your current total is %s $' % groceries[grocery]

main()
```

For several inputs use (not tested, py3k code, remember to convert costs to floats before):

```
total = 0
while True:
  grocery = input('Enter an item: ')
  if grocery == 'EXIT':
       print('Your final total is $%s' %total)
       break
  else:
       cost = groceries[grocery]
       total += cost
       print('Your current total is $%s' %total)
```

Comment: Thanks, I am using python 3.2.1.

Answer (score 0):

Two things: eggs + bread == 1.17 + 1.50 != 3.00...

Secondly, you could (for such a small text file) write a routine that builds the dictionary up front by alternating the even/odd lines as key:value pairs (or testing the type() as either str or float, and figure it out that way). Traversing the text file repeatedly costs more than referencing a stored variable in memory.

Also, this approach makes it simpler to get the step one working, so you can focus on step two and be certain the code behind you works, and makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, though I am still confused by your meaning.